How do I slow down audio in ffmpeg by more than half (*NO* tempo correction)
I have video that I want to slow down to 1/4 speed using ffmpeg. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the audio to slow down without any attempt to maintain pitch. Everything I find by searching is about how to use the atempo feature to slow down audio while maintaining pitch. I want the opposite.
The best I figured out was to use "asetrate=44100/2", but the sound wasn't as good when I play it slow in VLC (also without tempo correction). I'd like to do this all in one command if possible. All I want to do is change the PTS of the audio just like the video.
Simply setting a PTS on the audio did not work either (invalid argument)
Isn't this kind of slowdown the most technically simple? It's literally just playing it slower with adjustment of any kind. Surely ffmpeg can do this?
